# docker not publishing ports on one machine

Tags: docker

I'm running this command on two linux machines:

```
docker run -d --name registry --restart=always -p 4000:5000 -v registry:/var/lib/registry registry:2
```

One one, the port gets published, as expected:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE        COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                    NAMES
0cae195defe8   registry:2   "/entrypoint.sh /etc…"   3 seconds ago   Up 2 seconds   0.0.0.0:4000->5000/tcp   registry
$ ss -nltp|grep 4000
LISTEN 0      4096         0.0.0.0:4000       0.0.0.0:*
```

On the other it does not:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE        COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS     NAMES
5d3726252a61   registry:2   "/entrypoint.sh /etc…"   4 seconds ago   Up 3 seconds             registry
$ ss -nltp|grep 4000
$
```

What could cause docker not to publish that port on the second machine?

N.B. A restart of the machine did not do the trick.

**Edit** Docker version of the machine where port publishing does not work:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           20.10.17
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.17.11
 Git commit:        100c701
 Built:             Mon Jun  6 23:03:17 2022
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.17
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.17.11
  Git commit:       a89b842
  Built:            Mon Jun  6 23:01:23 2022
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.6
  GitCommit:        10c12954828e7c7c9b6e0ea9b0c02b01407d3ae1
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.2
  GitCommit:        v1.1.2-0-ga916309
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

The docker version of the machine where it is working is exactly the same, except that the client has one more line:

```
 Cloud integration  0.1.18
```

Comment: Are both machines running the same distribution and docker version? In the second example, if you attempt to access the service on port `4000`, is it available despite not showing up in `ss` output?

Comment: @larsks I've added version information to the question. Are you seriously suggesting a TCP port could be listened on even though `ss -nlt` does not list it? I could not connect to the port, I verified with telnet. That's the reason I double-checked with the definitive `ss -nlt`.

Comment: Yes, through the magic of iptables it is possible to accept connections on a port which will not show up in `ss/netstat/etc`. Welcome to technology :).

Comment: @larsks However it would at least show up in `docker ps`, if docker was publishing it. Which of course it does not. Or do you think the firewall could actually be preventing docker from publishing it in the first place (rather than just blocking packets)?